# Filter on generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a function using TypeScript that will allow me to filter a list of objects depending on their type. The result should be a function that will allow me to do either:

```
filter<Foo>(items);
```

or

```
filter(items, Foo);
```

I've been trying to do it in the following way:

```
class Foo {
    public constructor(public name: string, public type: string) {

    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }

const items: Foo[] = [
    new Foo('Foo', 'A'),
    new Bar('bar', 'A'),
    new Foo('baz', 'B'),
];

const filter = <T extends Foo>(items: any[], typeT: T): T[] => {
    return items.filter(item => item instanceof typeT)
};

console.log(filter(items, Foo));
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I make this work?

[TypeScript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string%2C%20public%20type%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20items%3A%20Foo%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Foo('Foo'%2C%20'A')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Bar('bar'%2C%20'A')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Foo('baz'%2C%20'B')%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20filter%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Foo%3E(items%3A%20any%5B%5D%2C%20typeT%3A%20T)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20items.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item%20instanceof%20typeT)%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(filter(items%2C%20Foo))%3B)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass in the type you are actually passing in the constructor of the class. Your signature is passing in an instance of `T`. You should try:

```
const filter = <T extends Foo>(items: any[], typeT: new (...params : any[]) => T): T[] => {
    return items.filter(item => item instanceof typeT)
};
```

**Note:** In your example all the items in the array will pass the filter, because `Bar` is derived from `Foo` and thus is also an instance of `Foo`. If you want only object of type `Foo` and not derived, you could use `item.constructor == typeT`

Comment: Is it also possible to do something like this without a class reference, but just a Type? E.g. the type would be "Foo" and it's not an instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What would a call to this method look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by using the `name` property of the class:

```
class Foo {
    public constructor(public name: string, public type: string) {

    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }

const items: Foo[] = [
    new Foo('Foo', 'A'),
    new Bar('bar', 'A'),
    new Foo('baz', 'B'),
];

const filter = (items: Foo[], typeT: Function): Foo[] => {
    return items.filter(item => item.constructor.name === typeT.name)
};

console.log(filter(items, Foo)); // Array [ {…}, {…} ]
```