# How to filter an array based on type parameters typeof

Tags: typescript, entity-component-system

I want to write a simple entity component system.

```
class Component {
}


class Entity {

  readonly components: Array<Component> = []

}

class T extends Component {}
class F extends Component {
    get hello() { return 'world' }
}

class World {

  readonly entities: Array<Entity> = []
  readonly components: Map<typeof Component, Array<Component>> = new Map()

  first_entity(T: typeof Entity) {
    return this.entities.find(_ => _ instanceof T)
  }

  all_entities(T: typeof Entity) {
    return this.entities.filter(_ => _ instanceof T)
  }

  first<T extends Component>(ctor: { new(...args: any[]): T }) {
    return this.components.get(ctor)
  }

  constructor() {

    this.components.set(T, [new T()])
    this.components.set(F, [new F(), new F()])

    console.log(this.first<F>(F))

  }
}

let world = new World()
```

I want to do this:

```
world.first<FComponent>() 
// returns the first instance of an FComponent 
// that extends Component.
```

of course there are instances of bunch of different components, so I want to keep them in a map with a key `typeof SubComponent`.

[Filter on generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637124/filter-on-generic-types)

[Using a generic type argument with `typeof T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249906/using-a-generic-type-argument-with-typeof-t)

I've seen these answers and came up with the above code, but it only works if I have to type FComponent twice like this:

`world.first<F>(F)`

where I want this:

`world.first<FComponent>() // returns the first instance of an FComponent that extends Component.`

### Edit:

So what I actually want is world.first() to return something of type FComponent so I can dispatch methods on that specific class.

This signature:
`first<T extends Component>(ctor: { new(...args: any[]): T }): T`

This should type correct:
`world.first<F>()?.hello`

This shouldn't compile:

`world.first<T>()?.hello`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQF2gbwFgAoAX2PKNEhgBVoMAPbLAExgRXS1zzMvCjQAYvSat2SVJhz4+xKoIDq8AE4gW+CtGgqMYFuhABPaMElccEAFzQAsmGQAebEeQZ4AMzjnp2ADTQAIIqKmBGjhxS3AB80dAAvNCYAO52DgAUAJRa0B4AlioQ2I50jMxobN6cvtHpwNiqNnhJGMnpAHSdYCoA5tbQYGhGANoAupk2dCSZmkTa2rrYAK4qaNDYABZ5EO1m1dw7PRjYdQ0q2XPQcpdmaEUqS-WqWbPE8+tbO3tRlu0Qx+kaAFhiloDQsuM3vNNttdj4Dn8AUJgaChFkAqiIRcodpbhB4CAMO0QPAeukYTt8oVikJakJMtjLnxrqDlGoWFkgA

Comment: Why do you need to use `first<F>(F)`? Seems like `first(F)` works now: https://tsplay.dev/mq3BYw

Comment: I edited my answer, does your instance can dispatch methods from F type.

Comment: Just needs some small changes: https://tsplay.dev/NB5XVw

Comment: Your version works, but If I remove the first definition with the type parameters it doesn't work. Some kind of function overloading happens here but I don't know how it works. Please post an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract the signature into an overload, then it won't get in the way of the implementation. Even though the definition of first has the signature `(ctor: typeof Component) => T`, the *external signature* is `<T extends Component>(ctor: { new (...args: any[]): T }) => T | undefined`.

```
  first<T extends Component>(ctor: { new(...args: any[]): T }): T | undefined;
  first(ctor: typeof Component) {
    return (this.components.get(ctor) ?? [])[0] // small change to impl
  }
```

Then you'll be able to use it:

```
new World().first(F)?.hello // OK
//          ^? inferred as <F>(ctor: typeof F) => F | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YqNTwIA)